# Outlook rule: move to specific folder if sender is in specific group

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I have to create a rule in an Outlook 2013 with following condition: move an email from any user, which are in specific user group.

For example if an user `John` is member of an group `MoveMe` then any mails from this user should be moved to a specific folder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of group are you using? It is a Distribution List?  Is it stored in your own Outlook mailbox or in an Exchange environment?

Comment: I'm not quite sure: I can look on a user card by hovering mouse pointer onto the photo or name of user, then appears a modal window with detailed user info, then by mooving to a tab membership(not sure about the name of the tab - it's on a Russion on my desktop) and then would be a list of groups, for example `thisisagroup@` and `thisisanothergroup@`

Comment: It is [suggested that](http://superuser.com/a/241485/257269) _"...you can make a distribution list, then apply the rule in step one to "from people or distribution list" and choose the distribution list you created...To create a new distribution list open your contacts and hit ctrl+shift+L..."_. Let me know if it is ok for you...

Comment: I tried this, and this works, but in fact it works just like @John said

Answer (score 2):

You can create a message rule in Outlook 2013 based on a Contact group but it will convert the group into a list of email addresses based off that group. So if you change the Contact group addresses, you will need to recreate the rule again using the updated group.

You can use a Contact group when creating a "Search Folder". But this won't move the emails.

Comment: That's work for me, but not in that way I want. But I guess, not all wishes will come true. So, thanks..)